# Store and read files from external storage in Xamarin Forms app

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a requirement where I want to provide the ability to users to backup their app data and restore it later (e.g. when they want to switch the phone). I want the backup to be done in an external storage (like iCloud on iPhone and SD card on Android). The location and file name should be picked by users. Subsequently, they can pick up this file on another device or same device and restore the data. How do I provide this facility to pick file location in my xamarin forms app?

Thanks
Naweed

Answer (score -1):

You can try below Plugin

Plugin Name :- Xam.Plugin.FilePicker

Nuget Link :- **[Plugin Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.FilePicker)**

Nuget Library code Link :- **[FilePicker Plugin Link](https://github.com/Studyxnet/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows)**

Comment: I tried. This is good for picking already saved files. I also want the user to specify a location and filename where the backup data file should be stored.